# How to remove noise from a DSM (city center) to create a 3D printable model

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, dem, noise

For the company I work for, I need to create a 3D printable model of a part of a city's downtown area.

At my disposal (upon request to local government authorities) I have point clouds from LiDAR scans (detail about 0.5 m) of the area, and the workflow that I have found is to use this data to generate the DSM. However, I manage to generate the DSM with difficulty, having to use paid software (I tested a trial version of Agisoft Metashape) and the result did not convince me.

Again through the local authorities I was able to get the DSM generated by them directly.
Using QGIS and the DEMto3D plugin, I was able to make printable 3D models. Unfortunately, this procedure absolutely does not allow me to achieve the required quality for the project.
In order for everyone to understand what I mean, I report below some evidence.

A small excerpt of the DSM is this:

[image: DSM excerpt of the entire area]

and below is an enlarged detail:

[image: DSM detail]

The jagged edges of the buildings transfer to the 3D model and the effect is anything but pleasant, as can be seen from the 3D model opened in Blender.

[image: 3D model with jagged edges]

My idea to improve the result was to try reprocessing/filtering the two-dimensional DSM image, rather than the 3D model. Searching the net, I came across the algorithm of Stevenson and Sun from Cardiff University and tried its implementation via the SAGA Mesh Denoise command in QGIS.
After several trials I could not get anything satisfactory. Many details are lost, the edges of buildings remain jagged and some roofs rounded.

I think I've described all the tests I've done, and I can't think of anything else to do.
I hope to find some suggestions on filters to apply or even a completely new methodology.

I leave a link from where you can download the DSM fragment I showed above.

[Tiles.82.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jPKwCI6chbTENuxzOBvq4dKTZHLamsOB/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Can you use polygons, e.g. from OpenStreetMap, for the shapes and add a mean hights from the DEM to these polygons? Or use GRASS tool `r.reclass` to reclassify your raster?